# How to pad null characters to list item in python?

Tags: python

Python newbie here. I have the following list:

```
['G1X1.000Y-3.000', 'G2X-1.000Y-3.000I-1.000J-2.291', 'G1X-1.000Y0.000', 'F0']
```

And I would like to pad each of the string list items with an ASCII null '\0' in order to make each of these strings 32 characters or bytes long (I have an embedded application running on a microcontroller which is to receive 32 bytes long strings over serial communications).

I tried the following thinking it would work however when I print the list again there seems to be no change.

```
#Format each command to a 32 character long string
for i in fileContents:
    length = len(i)
    print(length)
    spacesToAdd = (32 - length)
    i += ''*spacesToAdd

print(fileContents)
```

I expected to see something like this for the first list item:

```
['G1X1.000Y-3.000\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0',]
```

However the print statement shows no change:

```
['G1X1.000Y-3.000', 'G2X-1.000Y-3.000I-1.000J-2.291', 'G1X-1.000Y0.000', 'F0']
```

Comment: try using `'\0'` instead of `''`

Comment: Neither of these directly address your question, but consider using the `ljust` method, and consider using `bytes` instead of `str` when dealing with data that needs to be a certain number of bytes long. Unicode characters in a string can take up a greater number of bytes than the string's `len` might suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ljust` method.

```
for i, s in enumerate(fileContents):
    fileContents[i] = s.ljust(32, '\0')
```

In your code, `i` is just a reference to the string, not a reference to the "slot", so you aren't modifying your list. You need to assign your new `str` object directly to the list slot.